# sns.set() is nullifying legend parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am attempting to add shading to a seaborn countplot legend, but it isn't working.  The only thing I seem to be able to alter is legend placement and fontsize.  I'll demonstrate with a simple example (this example comes from https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/legend.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make some fake data.
a = b = np.arange(0, 3, .02)
c = np.exp(a)
d = c[::-1]

# Create plots with pre-defined labels.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a, c, 'k--', label='Model length')
ax.plot(a, d, 'k:', label='Data length')
ax.plot(a, c + d, 'k', label='Total message length')

legend = ax.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True, fontsize='x-large')

# Put a nicer background color on the legend.
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('#00FFCC')

plt.show()
```

In this example, the shading appears correctly.  Using sns.set():

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
# Make some fake data.
a = b = np.arange(0, 3, .02)
c = np.exp(a)
d = c[::-1]

# Create plots with pre-defined labels.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a, c, 'k--', label='Model length')
ax.plot(a, d, 'k:', label='Data length')
ax.plot(a, c + d, 'k', label='Total message length')

legend = ax.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True, fontsize='x-large')

# Put a nicer background color on the legend.
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('#00FFCC')

plt.show()
```

Now the loc and fontsize parameters still work, but shading does not appear.  Is there a way to add shading when using sns.set()?  Thanks

Edit: I failed to mention that I am using a custom method output_plot() to display these images on a web page.  So instead of plt.show() I am using print(output_plot()) with the following method:

```
def output_plot(clickable=False):
    from io import BytesIO
    import base64
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    output = ""
    fig = plt.gcf()

    if clickable:
        large_image = BytesIO()
        fig.savefig(large_image, format='png')
        large_image.seek(0)
        large_image = base64.encodebytes(large_image.getvalue()).decode()

    fig.set_size_inches([13.0/2,8.0/2])
    small_image = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(small_image, format='png')
    small_image.seek(0)
    small_image = base64.encodebytes(small_image.getvalue()).decode()

    if clickable:
        output = """<span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                <a href="javascript:(
                    function(){
                        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                            title: 'Graph',
                            height: 800,
                            width: 1100,
                            layout: 'fit',
                            html: '<img src=\\\'data:image/png;base64,%s\\\'/>'
                        }).show();
                    }
                )()">
                    <img src='data:image/png;base64,%s'/>
                </a>
            </span>""" % (large_image, small_image)
    else:
        output = """<span style="white-space: nowrap;">                
                        <img src='data:image/png;base64,%s'/>
                    </span>""" % small_image

    return output
```

I'm on matplotlib version 1.5.1 and seaborn version 0.7.1

Comment: [this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai43H.png) I get when running the bottom code from the question. It seems to work correctly.

Comment: I did fail to mention that I'm using a custom output_plot method to display the figure as a PNG on a webpage

Comment: Unless that "custom output_plot method" removes the legend frame, that should not matter. However, you may of course replicate this method in the question to let others have a look at it. I would rather think that you may be using some old versions of the libraries.

Comment: Thank you, ImportanceOfBeingErnest.  I'm working with an external vendor and they are using using matplotlib version 1.5.1 and seaborn version 0.7.1.  I will add the custom output_plot() method

Comment: What I can say already is that the `output_plot` method is harmless. I can also reproduce the undesired output with matplotlib 1.5.3 and seaborn 0.7.1. So a solution is for sure to update matplotlib and seaborn.

Comment: Thanks for your help!